# how to reduce node_modules in npm

Tags: node.js, npm, frontend, node-modules

when i start a project i always use npm and every start i will use

> npm install

and will make `node_modules` directory inside.

When finished making the project I was surprised by the size of the file is almost 200Mb.
Imagine if creating more projects. My disk capacity will be burdened.

[project capacity](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1V1l1.png)

Is there any way to **prevent/reduce** the size on my project folder.
For example make one file `node_modules` to be used repeatedly?

Answer (score 7):

Using `--save` and `--save-dev` when adding dependencies will make your project more size-aware. For development size is "fine" but for production, npm will only install what ever is in `dependencies` of your `package.json` thus decreasing your `node_modules` size (in production).

Otherwise `npm prune` is a great way to clean up unused modules further decreasing the size of your project. Other than that being aware of which modules you install will be the only sure-fire way of decreasing project size.

Answer (score 4):

If you use VSCode, you can use this extension:
[Import Cost](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=wix.vscode-import-cost)

This will show you next to your requires how much space does the particular node module take, then estimate do you need a 20 MB lib for 2 features in it :)

Answer (score 0):

Which version of **npm** are you using? If you are using **npm** 5 and up it will help deduplicate packages. I will also recommend that you remove unnecessary packages. **node_modules** can get pretty huge depending on what dependencies you are using in your app so I am not sure what we can do about that to be honest.

Comment: I use npm version **3.5.2** is it different?